# Grails Integration testing: problems with get

Tags: unit-testing, grails, integration-testing, mocking, grails-orm

I'm trying to write a simple integration test, but having some trouble with Domain Objects. I've read on [unit testing](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1/guide/9.%20Testing.html) but can't figure it out.

This is my simple test:

```
    User user = User.get(1)

    controller.params.userid = "1"
    controller.session.user = user

    controller.save();
```

The error message is:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method: static
>   com.baufest.insside.user.User.get() is
>   applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.Integer) values: [1](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1/guide/9.%20Testing.html)

My guess is that I should mock the `user` object, but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you're integration testing, but it looks like you're unit testing. Is the test under test/integration or test/unit? Unit tests need mocking, but integration tests have an initialized Spring application context and Hibernate, and run against an in-memory database.

This is described in the user guide, which is at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ (you reference an older 1.1 version).

To mock the User class, just call mockDomain with one or more test instances either in setUp or in the test method:

```
def users = [new User(...), new User(...), ...]
mockDomain User, users

...

User user = User.get(1)
```

Comment: Its under IntegrationTests. What I'm trying to do is to test a controller, that retrieves the user object from session inside its save() method.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a missing method exception unless you're doing something funky. Are you extending GroovyTestCase? Integration tests should, but unit tests would extend one of the Grails unit test classes like ControllerUnitTestCase.